# Can anyone help on this This method must return a result of type int

Tags: java, integer, return, return-value, return-type

I am stuck in here I want to print these values but it just doesn't allow me. Help please

```
public int horaPraticada(Intervalo crime) {
    if (inicio != crime.getStart() && fim != crime.getEnd()) {
    
        return  (crime.getEnd() - crime.getStart()); }
        
    if (inicio > crime.getStart() && fim < crime.getEnd()) {
        return  (crime.getEnd() - crime.getStart());
    }
    if (inicio == crime.getStart() && fim > crime.getEnd()) {
        
        return (crime.getEnd() - crime.getStart());
    }
    if (inicio != crime.getStart() && fim == crime.getEnd()) {
        return (crime.getEnd() - crime.getStart());
    
    }
    
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: You need an additional `return` statement outside of the `if` conditionals.

Comment: Since each if block contains exactly the same return result then @GaryNLOL 's answer is the way to go.

Comment: Point is not how to make this work; but the bad design. Correct your design and perform a code coverage test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To further improve GriffeyDog's answer: the compiler does not know, if it is possible or not that all conditions fail. If they would all fail, then the method would not return anything. Therefore, you need to add a return statement outside of the conditions.

Comment: Yes it worked!! Thanks a looot!

Answer (score 0):

Why do not doing this?

```java
public int horaPraticada(Intervalo crime) {
     return (crime.getEnd() - crime.getStart());   
}
```